# Turning ANSI_WARNINGS off permanently at the database level with alter command not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

My goal is to turn off `ANSI_WARNINGS` at the database level permanently. I understand the risks.

The command that I'm using is

```
ALTER DATABASE <DB_NAME>  
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
```

However, when I try to insert a big value( beyond what is defined for the column) into a column I still get

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Please help me with making the alter command work permanently

Comment: That is not a warning, its a big error message.

Comment: That is the error you would get if you try to insert something that is "bigger" than what the column allows for. If you do execute such statements, you should verify that you only insert something that fits the column.

Comment: Even if the `SET` options did what you wanted, setting these options at the DB level is useless if the connecting application provides its own settings, and almost all modern client libraries do. Because they are per-session and the session setting always takes priority, there is no way to turn these options on or off "permanently". All this is a lot of words for saying: fix your design or constrain yourself to stored procedures that do precisely what you need and nothing else (you can set any options you like as well as do things like truncation there).

Comment: @EzLo `ANSI_WARNINGS` **does** do what they want but is presumably overriden by the client as Jeroen says.  BTW a lot of SQL Server features require this setting to be `ON` anyway.